# Sort from Release Date to number of movies to specific Genres

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I am taking a CSV file of a movie title, genres, tickets sold, and release dates and trying to sort the number of movies released per month by specific genres. How could I get across from doing this?

I have tried using df commands like the code below, the command works for printing movies per month but I need movies per month by specific genres like Horror, Action, Comedy.

```
print(df.groupby(df['Release Date'].dt.month)['Movie'].count()['Genre'])
```

These are the results based on the code above without ['Genre'] involved. How could I take this, instead of 1  39, it can be 1 5 Horror or 1 6 Comedy, and so forth down the months?

```
1     39
2     43
3     62
4     74
5     46
6     58
7     62
8     61
9     80
10    61
11    50
12    43
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: print(df.groupby(df['Release Date'].dt.month)['Movie'].count()['Genre']) And i get an error saying KeyError: 'Genre'

Comment: please provide sample data  and your expected output,

Comment: Not the best with Pandas, fairly new, I am in love with its simplicity but its complex at the same time.

Comment: Movie Release Date Distributor Genre MPAA Tickets Sold
1,000 Rupee Note 9/23/2016 Kino Lorber Drama Not Rated 277
10 Cloverfield Lane 3/11/2016 Paramount Pictures Thriller/Suspense PG-13 8,333,294
13 Hours: The Secret Soldiers of Benghazi 1/15/2016 Paramount Pictures Drama R 6,110,198
2016 Oscar Shorts 1/29/2016 ShortsHD Multiple Genres Not Rated 325,643
20th Century Women 12/25/2016 A24 Drama R 20,644
3 Weeks in Yerevan 9/16/2016 Richmond Media Entertainment Comedy Not Rated 3,380

Comment: Sample data means show us your df

Comment: my df is a 680 row 6 column csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192681/discussion-between-hoonin-and-wen-ben).

Comment: @Hoonin, you can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question, which is better than trying to add more information as comments.